# Discord.js - How do you move a user that reacts to an embed?

Tags: discord.js

I am new to Discord js and I am trying to make my bot move all users that react to an embed into a certain voice channel. Currently, it takes whoever wrote the message and moves them to the specified voice channel.I tried many combinations of user.id, guild.member, etc. What would I put before the .setVoiceChannel? I am confused as to what message.member is other than the person that wrote the message. Thank you!

```js
collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.emoji.name == reactionControls.VOID) {
     const channel = message.guild.channels.find('name', 'Void 1');
     message.member.setVoiceChannel(channel);
  }
});
```

Comment: What version are you on?

Comment: Wow I just checked and I guess I am still on v10.16.3... I haven't used node for a while as you can probably tell. It looks like they made a ton of changes in future versions.

Comment: I was asking about what discord.js version, not node.

Comment: Oh sorry. I am using version 11.5.1.

Comment: You might have not gotten a notification, so to remind you I updated and undeleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`message.member` does refer to the user who execute the command, if you want the member who reacted you will have to convert `user` using `<GuildMember>.fetchMember`, the only issue now is that the collect event doesn't give the parameter of user in v11.5.1 so you will need to just use `collector.users.last()` to get the last reactor

```js
collector.on('collect', async (reaction) => {
  if (reaction.emoji.name == reactionControls.VOID) {
     const channel = message.guild.channels.find('name', 'Void 1');
     const user = collector.users.last();
     const member = await message.guild.fetchMember(user);
     member.setVoiceChannel(channel);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! For some reason there is an error that there is an invalid or cached id provided at guild.fetchMember.

Comment: Can you show me the full error code? Add it to your post or send a link

Comment: Looks like in v11.5.1 they don't give the user parameter, added a quick hack.

Comment: Hm I still seem to be getting the same errors. Do you think it would be better to update my version and update my code accordingly? It seems like this version is strange and the documentation on discord.js isn't the greatest. Thanks for your help I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I agree this version isn't the best, but the documentation for it is still great. As for updating yes I think it's worth it, especially since I believe anything before v12 expires in October. It'll take a while to update everything though.